# Array not returning the expected output

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to get user input and store it on an array but I can't seem to get the correct output, when I `console log` the results I get different arrays with 0 length

Here's my code.

```
let bambooInputElement = document.querySelector('.bambooInputElement');

let bambooTotal = [];

function calculateBamboo() {
    bambooInputElement = bambooInputElement.value;

    if (bambooInputElement < 25) {
        alert('Pledge must be at least $25.');
    }else {
        let amountDonated = 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < bambooTotal.length; i++) {
            bambooTotal.push(bambooInputElement);
            amountDonated = amountDonated + bambooTotal[i];
        }
    }
}
bambooBtnElement.addEventListener('click', calculateBamboo);
```

Comment: You're not pushing into your list at all, the condition `bambooTotal` is always zero and hence nothing is ever pushed into the list, bring the `push` statement outside of the for loop, and try to add clarifications to what you wanna do with `amountDonated` too.

Comment: `bambooInputElement = bambooInputElement.value;` is quite suspect. What is `bambooInputElement` to start with? Why are you replacing that initial value with `bambooInputElement.value`? The second time you call `calcualteBamboo`, `bambooInputElement` will be the `bambooInputElement.value` from the previous call.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Aside from the two issues noted above, there isn't enough information here for us to effectively help you. Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: ````bambooInputElement```` is the html input element hence I'm reassigning it, ````bambooInputElement = bambooInputElement.value;```` I want the value the user enters and push it on the ````bambooTotal```` array when a button is clicked

Comment: Could you please create a [mcve] ? That means a minimal JS / HTML and if needed CSS?

Comment: Cool, I will edit this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `bambooInputElement` is exactly what it says - and **that's an Element**, not its value - *don't* reassign types. Use a new variable instead.
- [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) should be outside of the loop. Actually you don't need a `for` loop at all, use *Reduce*.
- Use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to reduce an array to a single value (the total amount)
- Use `return` inside a function to return a result / or an alert - if that's what you want.

```js
const bambooInputElement = document.querySelector('.bambooInputElement');
const bambooBtnElement = document.querySelector('.bambooBtnElement');

const bambooDonations = []; // this is not total, those are donations!

function calculateBamboo() {
  const val = parseFloat(bambooInputElement.value);
  if (val < 25) return alert('Pledge must be at least $25.');
  // Add to array of donations
  bambooDonations.push(val);
  // Get total donations
  const totalDonations = bambooDonations.reduce((a, v) => a+=v, 0);
  // Reset input value
  bambooInputElement.value = "";
  console.log(totalDonations); // TEST ONLY
  // return that total:
  return totalDonations;
}

bambooBtnElement.addEventListener('click', calculateBamboo);
```

```html
<input type="number" class="bambooInputElement">
<button type="button" class="bambooBtnElement">CALCULATE</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `bambooTotal.push(bambooInputElement)` should be before the for loop. This is because, without pushing an element in the array, the length will always be zero hence it won't enter in the array.
Putting that line out of the for loop will ensure that the value get's entered and then the array is of atleast length 1.

Comment: This works but it creates a new list every time I click the button, it doesn't add the values on the same array